# ¿CÓMO BUSCO UN ELEMENTO EN UNA ARREGLO DE STRING JAVA?

Tags: array, arraylist

Pedir un nombre a buscar, leer ese nombre desde teclado y recorrer el arreglo para verificar si existe,
si se encuentra mostrar un mensaje indicando que si se encuentra el nombre x en caso contrario
mostrar una leyenda no se encuentra el nombre x.

este es mi codigo pero a la hora de ejecutar y llegar a comparar los elementos solo toma el último elemento del arreglo y ese es el que compara los demás son omitidos.

```
package arrreglo_practicas;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Arrreglo_Practicas {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
       
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String busqueda = "";
        int  elements = 0 ;
        String aux = null ;
        //tomando el valor e insertarlo en el arreglo 
        
        elements = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "digite la cantidad  de elementos  del areglo "));
        //arreglo de "n" elementos 
        
        String [] arreglo = new String [elements];
        
        //recorriendo el arreglo para que tome los valores 
   
        for (int x = 0;  x <arreglo.length; x++){
            System.out.print("|ingresa  los nombres| ");
            aux = input.nextLine();
            arreglo[x] = aux; 
        }
        //búsqueda inicial 
       busqueda = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null," busca un nombre:");
       
//parte que se ejecuta mal

        if (busqueda.equals(aux)){
            for (int a = 0; a < aux.length(); a++)
           System.out.println("si se encuentra el nombre:"); 
            
        }else {
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"dicho nombre no existe: ");
        }
         
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debe verificar la igualdad dentro del bucle `for` uno por uno con cada valor de matriz de entrada.

```
//parte que se ejecuta mal
     boolean isMatch = false;
    
        for (int a = 0; a < arreglo.length; a++) {
          if (busqueda.equalsIgnoreCase(arreglo[a])) {
            isMatch = true;
            System.out.println("si se encuentra el nombre:");
          }
        }
    
        if (!isMatch)
    
        {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "dicho nombre no existe: ");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo espero ayudarte con esta parte de tu código que he modificado.

```
for (int a = 0; a < arreglo.length; a++) {
        if (busqueda.equals(arreglo[a])) {
            System.out.println("si se encuentra el nombre:");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "dicho nombre no existe: ");
        }
    }
```

Recorre el arreglo y verifica si el nombre ingresado es igual al nombre que está en la posición arreglo[a]. Espero dejarme entender y ojalá te sirva